# MySQL Trigger - Trim and create 2 records

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, triggers

I'm a bit lost in an operation I need to do in my MYSQL database. I searched a lot but still couldn't find an answer.

Basically I have records that are insert in a wp_postmeta table this way:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| meta_id | post_id |  meta_key   |              meta_value              |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|     558 |     252 | coordinates | 39.74953310000001,-8.807682999999997 |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
```

What I would like to achieve (probably with a Trigger?) is splitting this record into two new records in the same table once that record is inserted, so that I could get:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+
| meta_id | post_id |    meta_key     |     meta_value     |
+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+
|     559 |     252 | _et_listing_lat | 39.74953310000001  |
|     560 |     252 | _et_listing_lng | -8.807682999999997 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

So the coordinates have to be splitted between lat and lng, the post_id is the same, meta_id auto-increment and meta_key as referred.

I understand I might have to use a support table to do this? I have been trying different solutions but still no luck... Any help? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this for existing record also? or just looking for new records.

Comment: Just for new records. Once the record is insert, the split must be done that way. Ideally the inserted recorded should be removed as well, after the two new ones are registered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `After Insert Trigger` in MySQL to do your job.

Try out this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER wp_postmeta_afr_ins 
AFTER INSERT ON wp_postmeta FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    insert into wp_postmeta (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
    select NEW.post_id,
          '_et_listing_lat ' as meta_key,
           substring_index(NEW.meta_value,',',1) 
    from wp_postmeta  
    union all
    select NEW.post_id,
          '_et_listing_lng ' as meta_key,
           substring_index(NEW.meta_value,',',-1) 
    from wp_postmeta ;  

   delete from wp_postmeta where meta_id =NEW.meta_id ;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem is I get this error:  #1442 - Can't update table 'wp_postmeta' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. And it seems that new records are not being passed to the wp_postmeta anymore. I read somewhere you can't update the same table directly with the trigger in MySQL. Maybe a stored procedure + trigger is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to get exactly the output I wanted but using a temporary table and slightly changing the code by code_monk. The following trigger is in wp_postmeta and inserts into wp_postmeta_support:

```
BEGIN

insert into wp_postmeta_support (post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
select NEW.post_id,
      '_et_listing_lat ' as meta_key,
       substring_index(NEW.meta_value,',',1) 
from wp_postmeta WHERE (SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id) = "location" 
union 
select NEW.post_id,
      '_et_listing_lng ' as meta_key,
       substring_index(NEW.meta_value,',',-1) 
from wp_postmeta WHERE (SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id) = "location";  

END
```

How do I transfer the records back to the original table (wp_postmeta)? It's diving me crazy because I always get the trigger error!! I even tried using an event to take the records back to triggered table but still no good...

Comment: I found a solution. I run an event every second that inserts and splits the records in the same table. No problems. Thanks